# Multiple SQL joins difficult query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

I have a weird schema but when it was designed it seemed like a good idea at the time. I have one *master* table, `lesson_objects`, that has foreign keys linking to the vocabulary, video and quizzes tables.

**vocab table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `se_vocab` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `vocab_word` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `vocab_audio` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `vocab_image` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

**video table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `se_video` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `video_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `video_description` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
    `video_file_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `video_url` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

**quizzes table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `se_quizzes` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `quiz_name` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    `quiz_description` TINYTEXT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

**lesson objects (contains foreign keys of previous tables)**

```
CREATE TABLE `se_lesson_org` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `lesson_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `section_object_type` ENUM('video','vocabulary','quiz') NOT NULL,
    `section_object_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I'm trying to create a query that returns all the records from lesson_objects but also includes the data in the columns for the type in that record (vocabulary, etc.)

For example:
[image]

Only my query returns no rows, while ideally it should turn multiple rows with every record containing SOME empty columns. E.g. if it isn't vocabulary, the columns for quiz and video will be empty.

My attempts are very bad, but here is one for the sake of guidance:

```
SELECT 
    lo.id, lo.section_object_type, lo.section_object_id, 
    vo.id, vo.vocab_text, vo.vocab_image, vo.vocab_audio
    vi.id, vi.video_name, vi.video_url,
    q.id, q.quiz_name
    FROM se_lesson_org lo, se_vocab vo, se_video vi, se_quizzes q
    WHERE lo.section_object_id = vo.id 
    OR lo.section_object_id = vi.id
    OR lo.section_object_id = q.id
```

Any help / comments would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Show sample data or create an sqlfiddle

Comment: Please post expected result format.

Comment: MySQL or/and SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved!

Comment: @jarlh Technically it's Google SQL storage but that wasn't an option, so it's a mixture of SQL and mysql (my best bet). Sorry I wasn't trying to spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to return all rows from `se_lesson_org`. Additionally, add a `JOIN` condition to match for the specific `section_object_type`

```
SELECT
    lo.*,
    vo.*,
    vi.*,
    q.*
FROM se_lesson_org lo
LEFT JOIN se_vocab vo
    ON vo.id = lo.section_object_id
    AND lo.section_object_type = 'vocabulary'
LEFT JOIN se_video vi
    ON vi.id = lo.section_object_id
    AND lo.section_object_type = 'video'
LEFT JOIN se_quizzes q
    ON q.id = lo.section_object_id
    AND lo.section_object_type = 'quiz'
```

---

*Note: Avoid using old-style JOIN syntax. Read this [**article**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) by Aaron Bertrand.*

Comment: Amazing stuff. Works perfectly. I'll take a look at that article. Thanks!

Comment: Nice article, @wewesthemenace. What does he mean when he talks about `*=, =*`? Probably a dumb question, but I'm not seeing it in the query he is referencing...

Comment: That's just the old-style syntax of `OUTER JOIN`. Note that the article is for `SQL Server` (MSSQL) but the principle can be applied to all RDBMs.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for a `LEFT JOIN` on each of these tables. That way if the foreign key is valid you will show values and if it isn't valid you will just get NULL for the related columns.

```
SELECT 
    lo.id, lo.section_object_type, lo.section_object_id, 
    vo.id, vo.vocab_text, vo.vocab_image, vo.vocab_audio
    vi.id, vi.video_name, vi.video_url,
    q.id, q.quiz_name
    FROM se_lesson_org lo
    LEFT JOIN se_vocab vo ON vo.id = lo.section_object_id 
        AND lo.section_object_type = 'vocabulary'
    LEFT JOIN se_video vi ON vi.id = lo.section_object_id 
        AND lo.section_object_type = 'video'
    LEFT JOIN se_quizzes q ON q.id = lo.section_object_id 
        AND lo.section_object_type = 'quiz'
```

Notice also how this syntax makes it clear how each table is being connected into the rest of the query rather than having a whole mess of conditions in the WHERE clause at the end.

Comment: Works great, and thank you for the explanation. I guess this is why I'm taking a SQL class this semester.